# What data type to use for ratings in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql

I am making a table right now, and I'm confused about what to use, because I used to use `smallint(6)` but it doesn't work in PostgreSQL.

Comment: What values can a "rating" have? 1-5, 1-7, 1-100, A-F? Can it have decimal places? Negative values?

Comment: 1-5 like a star rating, sorry for not saying that earlier

Comment: This is what the docs where created for [Integer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT). There is no option to specify the precision of an integer, you only have the option of `smallint/int2`, `integer/int4` or `bigint/int8`.

Comment: Can I maybe add something in the sql script to limit it externally? If there is even a need to limit it, and sorry if it is a dumb question im new to this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column can only have integer values between 1 and 5 you can use a `SMALLINT` for it with a `CHECK` constraint.

For example:

```
create table review (
  rating smallint not null check (rating between 1 and 5)
);
```

The `NOT NULL` constraint ensures the column always has values.

The `CHECK` constraint ensures values are always between 1 and 5, and that, for example, a value 6 won't be accepted.